# Mvc music store linq to sql shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, shopping-cart

I use Music store shopping cart code for my mvc project, but my project using linq to sql, not entity framework. I have changed the MusicStoreEntities class as following:

```
public class ShoppingCartEntities
{
    public ShoppingCartEntities()
    {
    }
    public List<h2t_Store_Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And these is ShoppingCart.cs class:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    ShoppingCartEntities storeDB = new ShoppingCartEntities();
    string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }
    // Helper method to simplify shopping cart calls
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(Controller controller)
    {
        return GetCart(controller.HttpContext);
    }
    public void AddToCart(h2t_Store_Product product)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and album instances
        var cartItem = (from data in storeDB.Carts
                        where data.CartId == ShoppingCartId && data.ProductID == product.ID
                        select data).Single();

        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            cartItem = new Cart
            {
                ProductID = product.ID,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Count = 1,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity
            cartItem.Count++;
        }
        // Save changes
        //storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
    public int RemoveFromCart(int id)
    {
        // Get the cart
        var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.Single(
            cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && cart.RecordId == id);

        int itemCount = 0;

        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            if (cartItem.Count > 1)
            {
                cartItem.Count--;
                itemCount = cartItem.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                storeDB.Carts.Remove(cartItem);
            }
            // Save changes
            // storeDB.SaveChanges();
        }
        return itemCount;
    }
    public void EmptyCart()
    {
        var cartItems = storeDB.Carts.Where(
            cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId);

        foreach (var cartItem in cartItems)
        {
            storeDB.Carts.Remove(cartItem);
        }
        // Save changes
        //storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
    public List<Cart> GetCartItems()
    {
        return storeDB.Carts.Where(
            cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId).ToList();
    }
    public int GetCount()
    {
        // Get the count of each item in the cart and sum them up
        int? count = (from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
                      where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                      select (int?)cartItems.Count).Sum();
        // Return 0 if all entries are null
        return count ?? 0;
    }
    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        // Multiply album price by count of that album to get 
        // the current price for each of those albums in the cart
        // sum all album price totals to get the cart total
        decimal? total = (from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
                          where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                          select (int?)cartItems.Count *
                          cartItems.product.UnitPrice).Sum();

        return total ?? decimal.Zero;
    }
    public int CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        decimal orderTotal = 0;

        var cartItems = GetCartItems();
        // Iterate over the items in the cart, 
        // adding the order details for each
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var orderDetail = new OrderDetail
            {
                AlbumId = item.ProductID,
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                UnitPrice = item.product.UnitPrice,
                Quantity = item.Count
            };
            // Set the order total of the shopping cart
            orderTotal += (item.Count * item.product.UnitPrice);

            storeDB.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        }
        // Set the order's total to the orderTotal count
        order.Total = orderTotal;

        // Save the order
        //storeDB.SaveChanges();
        // Empty the shopping cart
        EmptyCart();
        // Return the OrderId as the confirmation number
        return order.OrderId;
    }
    // We're using HttpContextBase to allow access to cookies.
    public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                context.Session[CartSessionKey] =
                    context.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
                context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
            }
        }
        return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
    }
    // When a user has logged in, migrate their shopping cart to
    // be associated with their username
    public void MigrateCart(string userName)
    {
        var shoppingCart = storeDB.Carts.Where(
            c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId);

        foreach (Cart item in shoppingCart)
        {
            item.CartId = userName;
        }
        //storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Anh Cart.cs class:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual h2t_Store_Product product { get; set; }

}
```

When i run project, i get an error:

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

[image]

Anyone can show me how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be run as linq-to-sql, but as linq-to-objects. The source for the linq query is  `ShoppingCartEntities.Carts` which is a `List<Cart>`.

The exception message indicates that `Carts` is `null` when executing the query. I can't see that you insantiate that list anywhere in the code provided.

If you've tried to convert this from an EF Code First example, it is easy to miss that step. When using EF Code First the entity sets automatically get values from the base class (presumable through reflection), but that "magic" does not exist in linq-to-sql.

Comment: Hi Anders, just as you said. I'm tried convert from "EF Code First" to "LINQ to SQL", this is not possible?

Comment: It is surely possible, but it looks like you are unfamiliar with LINQ to SQL, so you should do some tutorials on LINQ to SQL before trying the convert, so that you know what proper LINQ to SQL code looks like.

Comment: Yes, that right. I'm unfamiliar with LINQ to SQL, I will learn more. By the way, do you have a simple shopping cart code for mvc asp.net? I want to learning building a shopping cart on mvc but it's too difficult for me groping. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: That's another question, so post it as a new question. If this question is done, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark (if it was my answer that solved your problem).